# Custom Tags in Laravel Spark Templates?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, frontend, laravel-spark

In Laravel Spark, many of the vendor templates contain what look like custom tags.  For example, the `<spark-update-profile-photo/>` tag below.

```
#File: resources/views/vendor/spark/settings/profile/update-profile-photo.blade.php
<spark-update-profile-photo :user="user" inline-template>
    <!-- ... -->
</spark-update-profile-photo>
```

Are these tags hooks for some external front-end system?  How do they work?  Where would an experience PHP/Javascript programmer go to understand what these tags are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're Vue components. You'll find the docs for that js framework here: https://vuejs.org/, and here's a little info on extending Spark's Vue components: https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/client-customization. Laracasts has a full series on Vue which is free: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step.